# I looking to remove lower triangle in heatmap.2

Tags: r

I want to make a heatmap with only upper triangle. I have a small problem with it. One of the cell comes out of the triangle. Can someone help me with it.

Code I have used is:

```r
heatmap.2(data, Rowv = as.dendrogram(hclust(as.dist((1-data)/2), method = "ward.D")), Colv = "Rowv", cellnote = data, col = "palette", trace = "none")
```

```r
structure(list(Time = 0:24, pH = c(8.9, 9, 8.9, 9.2, 9.5, 9.5, 
9.5, 9.1, 9, 8.92, 8.8, 8.7, 8.84, 8.6, 8.9, 8.9, 8.97, 8.9, 
8.85, 8.7, 8.56, 8.4, 8.6, 8.6, 9.08), TDS = c(900L, 930L, 925L, 
920L, 919L, 900L, 915L, 845L, 875L, 984L, 875L, 800L, 715L, 710L, 
692L, 986L, 671L, 685L, 675L, 660L, 666L, 670L, 660L, 650L, 630L
), Conductivity = c(900L, 930L, 925L, 920L, 919L, 900L, 915L, 
845L, 875L, 984L, 875L, 800L, 715L, 710L, 692L, 986L, 671L, 685L, 
675L, 660L, 666L, 670L, 660L, 650L, 630L), Ca = c(350L, 384L, 
369L, 357L, 354L, 345L, 350L, 310L, 328L, 347L, 300L, 245L, 140L, 
125L, 120L, 168L, 118L, 100L, 120L, 134L, 160L, 145L, 138L, 120L, 
160L), Cl = c(95L, 109L, 105L, 101L, 100L, 94L, 109L, 85L, 98L, 
120L, 100L, 45L, 175L, 76L, 70L, 135L, 240L, 50L, 81L, 96L, 130L, 
160L, 142L, 137L, 270L), Mg = c(40L, 45L, 43L, 42L, 40L, 35L, 
33L, 28L, 32L, 45L, 42L, 35L, 60L, 57L, 49L, 60L, 28L, 30L, 21L, 
20L, 40L, 46L, 50L, 65L, 80L), TOC = c(1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 
1.25, 1.31, 1.34, 1.4, 1.3, 1.36, 1.45, 1.54, 1.3, 1.36, 1.34, 
1.5, 1.38, 1.4, 1.46, 1.5, 1.41, 1.49, 1.4, 1.35), Temperature = c(31, 
31.2, 30.8, 31.5, 30.2, 32, 32.7, 32.5, 33, 33.4, 34.9, 35, 34.7, 
35.2, 35, 35.8, 36.2, 36.4, 36, 37.4, 37.5, 37.5, 37.9, 38, 37.8
), HPCWater = c(0, 15, 24.6, 38.7, 48.6, 20.5, 35, 41, 50, 37, 
39, 41, 47, 36, 41, 45, 49, 35.8, 45.2, 50, 52, 34, 37.2, 40.5, 
47), HPCPVC = c(0, 43.5, 50, 65.8, 79, 55, 62, 74, 86, 60, 78, 
80, 84.5, 62, 72, 80, 80.2, 55, 68, 70, 80, 60, 76, 85, 80), 
    HPCGI = c(0L, 32L, 44L, 52L, 62L, 40L, 49L, 53L, 65L, 47L, 
    50L, 62L, 67L, 43L, 52L, 58L, 60L, 40L, 48L, 50L, 68L, 38L, 
    42L, 49L, 53L), HPCSS = c(0L, 25L, 29L, 32L, 36L, 24L, 30L, 
    39L, 42L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 40L, 29L, 34L, 36L, 39L, 27L, 30L, 
    38L, 41L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 38L), HPCCu = c(0L, 36L, 45L, 52L, 
    60L, 40L, 45L, 58L, 68L, 38L, 42L, 59L, 75L, 48L, 52L, 65L, 
    77L, 40L, 58L, 62L, 70L, 37L, 48L, 50L, 68L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Hi Srinivasa, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(data)` or if your data is very large `dput(data[1:10,])`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks ``` for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.